# Convert svg image from url to base64 in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, svg, base64

I would like to use `svg` image that I have from `url`, convert it to `base64`. Later on I am posting this image on social media platform. That is why I need it to be in `base64` format. How can I achieve that? I know how to do that when I have this picture on my website but how can I do that when I have only a link to that image?

Comment: @gre_gor I make like 50 requests for each image and it is only `node` server side. how do I download file there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code which can be used in node.js using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const download = async () => {
const response = await fetch("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg");
if (response.ok) {
    const buffer = await response.buffer();
    const base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
    return base64;
    }
}

(async () => {
const data = await download();
console.log(" ~ file: base64.js ~ line 12 ~ data", data);
})();
```

I'm using sample svg image from this [link](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg). Above code will return you base64 of the sample svg image :

```
PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMzAsMWg0MGwyOSwyOXY0MGwtMjksMjloLTQwbC0yOS0yOXYtNDB6IiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiLz4gCiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTMxLDNoMzhsMjgsMjh2MzhsLTI4LDI4aC0zOGwtMjgtMjh2LTM4eiIgZmlsbD0iI2EyMyIvPiAKICA8dGV4dCB4PSI1MCIgeT0iNjgiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iNDgiIGZpbGw9IiNGRkYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiPjwhW0NEQVRBWzQxMF1dPjwvdGV4dD4KPC9zdmc+Cg==
```

If you copy and paste this [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/svg), you will see the preview of the same image. Voila !!

Comment: I will check that out, by the way how do you use `import` in node.js project?

Comment: You can use babel-node to use ES6 syntax. Please try converting it to require for your existing project, hope it would still work fine with that. Please use the things inside download function, which is important.

Comment: Code works but the biggest problem is I cannot use that base64 in twitter API, I think this is because they allow only png files instead of svg

Comment: Ok great !! I think you need to find a workaround for things specifically related to twitter. If above things answers the question you asked, please accept and upvote. Thanks